# SELECT, JOIN and UPDATE at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, join

As more and more people do, I will use an sms api to send some people a reminder of their appointment today.

So I'm getting the data without any problems using this query:

```
SELECT users.id as userid, consultations.patient_id as patientid, consultations.title as patientname, patients.mphone as phone
FROM users
JOIN consultations
ON users.id = consultations.user_id
JOIN patients
ON consultations.patient_id = patients.id
WHERE users.sms > 0 AND DATE(consultations.start) = (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND patients.mphone <> ''
```

At the same time I'd like to update the consultations table and set `consultations.reminder = true` and `substract 1 from users.sms` for each row that is output for each `users.id`... Can I do that ?

My first problem is that if I add a `count()`, the query gets automatically grouped (or just the last line is shown, not sure why).

If you have a suggestion... :)

Comment: A select is read-only, it can't modify table data.

Comment: if you want to do many queries at the same time, then you should use Stored Procedures https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: Not sprocs. Transactions.

Answer (score 1):

My MySQL is a little bit rusty but you could insert your results into a temp table, and then update the other tables from there. Other than that, a select statement is not capable of modify data.

Try something like this;

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempAppointments AS (
SELECT users.id as userid, consultations.patient_id as patientid, consultations.title as patientname, patients.mphone as phone
FROM users
JOIN consultations
ON users.id = consultations.user_id
JOIN patients
ON consultations.patient_id = patients.id
WHERE users.sms > 0 AND DATE(consultations.start) = (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND patients.mphone <> '')


UPDATE C
SET reminder = true
FROM consultations AS C INNER JOIN TempAppointments AS T ON C.user_id = T.user_id

UPDATE U
SET sms = (sms - 1)
FROM Users AS U INNER JOIN TempAppointments AS T ON U.user_id = T.user_id
```

Remember to drop your temp table at the end though;

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE TempAppointments
```